# How to order a list of object using list::sort?

Tags: c++, list, sorting, lambda

I had to order a list of workers based on their overtime hours,so the first one would be the one who worked more overtime hours. I asked this before and the answer  got was to use this function with a lambda:

```
class Workers {
private:
    list<Worker> workers;
public:
    Workers() {
    }
    Workers(list<Worker> workers) {
        this->workers = workers;
    }
    void OvertimeHoursReport() {
        list<Worker> workers_Copy;
        workers_Copy = workers;
        workers_Copy.sort([](Worker& lh, Worker& rh) { return lh.Overtimehours() > rh.Overtimehours(); });
        for (list<Worker>::iterator it = workers_Copy.begin(); it != workers_Copy.end(); it++) {
            if ((it)->Overtimehours() > 0) {
                cout << "Name:";
                cout<<(it)->getName();
                cout << ' ';
                cout<<(it)->getLastname();
                cout << ' '<<"Sex: ";
                if ((it)->getSex() == true) {
                    cout << "Male" << ' ';
                }
                if ((it)->getSexo() == false) {
                    cout << "female" << ' ';
                }
                cout << "Overtime Hours: ";
                cout<<(it)->Overtimehours();
                cout << endl;
            }
        }

    }
};
```

It works fine, but I don't understand that much how lambdas work, even after reading about them online. Is there a way of doing the same thing but using the sort algorithm of list or any other method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It works fine, but I don't understand that much how lambdas work, even after reading about them online. Is there a way of doing the same thing but using the sort algorithm of list or any other method?

You are using the `sort` member function of `std::list`. There are two overloads of [`std::list::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort).

```
void sort();
template< class Compare >
void sort( Compare comp );
```

In your case, you are using the second overload. It allows custom compare functions to sort the items in the list. Use of a `lambda` function is one way to provide a custom compare function. You may use other ways of providing a custom compare function, such as:

1. A non-member function.

   ```
   bool compareWorkers(Worker const& lh, Worker const& rh)
   {
      return (lh.Overtimehours() > rh.Overtimehours());
   }
   ```

   and use it as:

   ```
   workers_Copy.sort(compareWorkers);
   ```
2. A `static` member function in `Workers`.

   ```
   static bool compare(Worker const& lh, Worker const& rh)
   {
      return (lh.Overtimehours() > rh.Overtimehours());
   }
   ```

   and use it as:

   ```
   workers_Copy.sort(Workers::compare);
   ```
3. A functor class.

   ```
   struct CompareWorkers
   {
      bool operator()(Worker const& lh, Worker const& rh) const
      {
         return (lh.Overtimehours() > rh.Overtimehours());
      }
   };
   ```

   and use it as:

   ```
   workers_Copy.sort(CompareWorkers());
   ```

Comment: On the first method, the non-member function must be on the `Worker` class, right? Not on `Workers`.

Comment: Yes. I'll fix the typo.

Answer (score 0):

no need for lambda just pass a compare function.

```
bool compareByOvertime(const Worker& lh,const Worker& rh)
{
    return lh.Overtimehours() > rh.Overtimehours();
};
```

or not a good way because it will confuse any programmer, declare the operator< in the worker class, because no one will expect this operator to compare on overtime.

Honestly stick with the lambda version.

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas are anonymous functions. So if you are not comfortable with lambdas, you can create a function for comparison based on your criteria. Then simply pass that function as an argument to the sort function.

Answer (score 0):

Really all that you are doing is using your lambda to construct your function object in place inside of the call to sort(). A method using a function declared and defined earlier is shown on cpp reference (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/).

So you are already using the sort method of list, you are just telling it which method to use to determine which object is less than the other. You could achieve the same thing without using the lambda.

This is untested, but should be the equivalent using a declared named method instead of a lambda.

```
bool CompareHours(Worker& lh, Worker& rh) { return lh.Overtimehours() > rh.Overtimehours(); }
void OvertimeHoursReport() {
    list<Worker> workers_Copy;
    workers_Copy = workers;
    workers_Copy.sort(CompareHours);
    for (list<Worker>::iterator it = workers_Copy.begin(); it != workers_Copy.end(); it++) {
        if ((it)->Overtimehours() > 0) {
            cout << "Name:";
            cout<<(it)->getName();
            cout << ' ';
            cout<<(it)->getLastname();
            cout << ' '<<"Sex: ";
            if ((it)->getSex() == true) {
                cout << "Male" << ' ';
            }
            if ((it)->getSexo() == false) {
                cout << "female" << ' ';
            }
            cout << "Overtime Hours: ";
            cout<<(it)->Overtimehours();
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The CompareHours function must be outside of the class, right? Like in the example from cpp reference.

Comment: As long as the function you give it is at the appropriate scope you should be OK. So both in the same class should work. The cop reference doesn’t use a class at all, to keep things minimal. But generally in a larger program having a function at global scope like that would be bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Without lambda:

```
bool isLess(Worker& lh, Worker& rh) { /* ... */ }

class Workers
{
    void OvertimeHoursReport()
    {
        list<Worker> workers_Copy(workers);
        workers_Copy.sort(isLess);
        // ...
    }
};
```

Lambdas are a convenient way to produce local functions that you otherwise would have do define explicitly, typically quite at a distance where you actually need them.

Actually, this is a bit short, lambdas are more like a functor, but can be converted to function pointer implicitly (or explicitly) *if* they do have an empty capture. Trying to explain them in full would exceed the scope of this answer, you should get a good C++ book for.

One thing about your constructor:

```
Workers(list<Worker> workers) // creates an intermediate _copy_(!) of parameter
// this->workers is initialized as empty here
{
    this->workers = workers; // now you assign by copying again!
}
```

You can spare the copy if you use a reference instead; you can initialise the member directly (sparing the empty initialisation) if you use the classes initialiser list (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`):

```
Workers(list<Worker> const& workers) // reference, no copy
    : workers(workers) // direct initialization
{ }
```

Variant:

```
Workers(list<Worker> workers) // the copy again!
    : workers(std::move(workers)) // now you move your copy into member
{ }
```

This variant could be used to produce a copy, but as well move an external list into:

```
Workers(someList); // copy!
Workers(std::move(someList)); // uses move constructor
                              // -> moves someList into temporary, from
                              // which it is moved again to member
```

You can avoid the intermediate entirely, but you then need two constructors for:

```
Workers(list<Worker> const& workers); // reference, as before, copies
Workers(list<Worker>&& workers)       // rvalue reference!
    : workers(std::move(workers))     // move!
{ }
```

Side note: [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) assures that parameter `worker` gets an rvalue again (which it wouldn't be any more without).